# htaccess Redirect with URL Parameters

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect all of my products from my old zen-cart store to my new shopify store.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} products_id=1408
RewriteRule ^ https://shop.xyz.com/collections/products/mno? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^products_id=1282 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://shop.xyz.com/collections/products/abc? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^products_id=12 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://shop.xyz.com/collections/products/xyz? [L,R=301]
```

However, I can't figure out why products_id 12 and 1282 both redirect to `https://shop.xyz.com/collections/products/xyz?`

Comment: No one has any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You line

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} products_id=12 [NC]
```

contains the expression: `products_id=12` which indeed matches both 12 and 1282.

If it's a single parameter, you can fix it by adding the end of string token `$`:  `products_id=12$`

Otherwise there will be a delimiter `&` after the products_id number.

https://example.com/shop/?products_id=12&cat_id=1

you could match it with:

`products_id=12&`

---

Another unorthodox but quick and dirty solution that may work is to sort the numbers down, the higher numbers will match correctly before hitting the lower number rules.